# How to extract sql query from Oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have Oracle report file (rdf file). I need to find what are the queries running (SQL queries) to extract data for this report.

As an example, how to find what is the query running once we click on save button related to this RDF file?

Comment: Open the RDF file, right click on the button; it will show the triggers associated with the button. Open the trigger code and follow the logic written inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the simplest way is to open that report in Reports Builder (which supports RDF version you have; I mean, Reports 2.5 probably won't open a RDF created in version 10g) and have a look at the data model editor.

Otherwise, do as I do it - open a RDF (or, if you have a JSP - even better) with a text editor (such as Notepad) and perform *search* through the file - search for `SELECT` keyword. You'll find some useless entries, but you'll certainly see useful ones as well. Copy them out of the RDF file and ... well, do whatever you planned to do with them.